# Why is $\int_{n}^{n+1}\int_{n}^x |f'(x)|\,dx \leq \int_{n}^{n+1} |f'(x)|\,dx$ for $x \in [n,n+1]$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, integration

Can anyone show me how to prove the following:

For $x\in \left [ n,n+1 \right ]$: $$\int_{n}^{n+1}\int_{n}^{x}\left | f'(t) \right |dtdx\leqslant \int_{n}^{n+1}\left | f'(t)\right |dt?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $n\leq x\leq n+1$: $\int_n^x|f'(t)|dt\leq \int_n^{n+1}|f'(t)|dt$ and if we integrate it with respect to $x$ over $[n,n+1]$, we get the expected result.

Comment: [+1 for writing what I would have written](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4154527#4154527)

Comment: @Davide Giraudo : Nice trick Davide. I really liked your proof.

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:*
The integral runs over the domain $n\leq t\leq x\leq n+1$. Interchanging the $x$ and $t$ integration, we have
$$\int_{n}^{n+1}\int_{n}^{x}\left | f^{'}(t) \right |dt\,dx = 
\int_{n}^{n+1}\int_{t}^{n+1}\left | f^{'}(t) \right |dx\,dt.$$
I am sure you can take it from here...

Comment: @ Fabian: I can definitely take it from here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$$\int_a^b \int_a^x g(t)\,dt\,dx=\int_a^b (b-x)g(x)\,dx$$

Why is this true? To go from the LHS to RHS intuitively, consider the fact that for $t\in [a,b]$, the double integral is set up to count $g(t)$ with generalized "multiplicity," or weight, proportionate to the length of the interval $[t,b]$ (this is the interval of $x$ values for which $t\in [a,x]$). To go from the RHS to the LHS algebraically, consider by-parts with $u=x-a,dv=g(x)$.